# Wrong timezone between .ics file and Google Calendar

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar

My .ics file looks somehow like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Calendar//task 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20200227T081353Z
DTSTART:20200228T060500Z
DTEND:20200228T140500Z
SUMMARY:working
UID:5b98ddce64856f69a9cbbb4b@calendar.dav.com
DESCRIPTION:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The problem is that when I import it into my Google Calendar, the time of the event is shown incorrectly. My timezone and Google Calendar timezone is UTC+1 while the event time is shown 06:05 - 14:05 while it should be 07:05 - 15:05.
Also worth to note that the timezone of .ics calendar (after adding to my Google Calendar) is shown as "GMT+00:00".

I tried to modify the .ics file and add for example
`TZID:/Europe/London`

after `BEGIN:VEVENT`

to hardcode the event timezone and "force" Google to recalculate event time based on my calendar timezone but it didn't work.

Any idas?

Answer (score 0):

The date of the event is 20200228 so, if your calendar is set to Europe/London, there is currently no UTC offset.

Europe/London will switch to UTC+1 on the 29th of March. See for example:

https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/uk/london

As a consequence, Google Calendar is showing the right time.